# Why am I getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:4000/products/add when trying to send http request?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to send a `json` to a server I wrote in `NodeJS`, a connection is made to the server,
For some reason I get a `FileNotFoundException`,
the log:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:4000/products/add
 at  com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
 at com.example.myfstrdbcontroller.SendProductJsonTask.doInBackground(SendProductJsonTask.java:39)
 at com.example.myfstrdbcontroller.SendProductJsonTask.doInBackground(SendProductJsonTask.java:21)`

my code:

```
public class SendProductJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String data = "";

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    try {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes("PostData="+strings[1]);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();

        while (inputStreamData != -1) {

            char current = (char) inputStreamData;

            inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();

            data += current;

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ccb", "doInBackground16: "+e.getCause());
        Log.d("ccb", "doInBackground17: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Log.d("ccb", "onPostExecute: "+s);
}
```

}

the code I do call the http request:

```
try {
                productJson(nameOfProduct, serialOfProduct, priceOfProduct, getGenderRB(), uriList, getColorsCB(), getSizeCB(), new JSONMadeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onJSONMade(JSONObject object) {
                        try {
                            SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        new SendProductJsonTask().execute("http://10.0.2.2:4000/products/add",object.toString());
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Remove wr.close();.

Comment: @blackapps same thing is happening

Comment: Did you checked what JSON string is generated by your object.toString() method ? With the same json string are you able to successfully invoke POST request from Postman ?

Comment: the json is fine, I did check it. I get from other method, strings of an array that contain other `jsons`. and when I print it from their method, it prints `[{"k","v"}]`, but when I do to the `json` `json.toString`, it prints: `{"colors":"[Ljava.lang.String;@862e0b4","gender":"F","imagesUri":"[]","name":"f","price":"f","serial":"f","sizes":"[Ljava.lang.String;@1c8b4dd"}`

Comment: this is the new json im creating:  `{"name":"f","serial":"f","price":"ff","gender":"M","color":"[{\"label\":\"Silver-Gold\",\"value\":\"Silver-Gold\"}]","size":"[{\"label\":\"S\",\"value\":\"S\"}]"}`                                    but for some reason, this is the json when it gets to the server: `{
  name: 'f',
  serial: 'f',
  price: 'ff',
  gender: 'M',
  color: '[{"label":"Silver-Gold","value":"Silver-Gold"}]',
  size: '[{"label":"S","value":"S"}]'
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your case

> httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

is throwing `FileNotFoundException` which means there is some problem with your server.

Try to check if post requests are actually working using https://www.codepunker.com/tools/http-requests .

Comment: I sent a POST request using Postman. and it worked.

Comment: i know that without adding internet permission (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection(); won't work, but out of curiosity did you add it to mainfest? Also, try adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in <application> tag of manifest

Answer (score 0):

So, at some places you get single quote and at some double quote at server side. I hope something like this might help -

```java
object.toString.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"").replaceAll("\"", "\\\"")
```

Comment: where do I need to change? in the server code or the app code?

Comment: tried to change it where I create the request body to: ` RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaTypeJson, String.valueOf(jsonObject).replaceAll("\"", "\\\""));` but still getting bad request

Comment: Both replaceAll methods are needed. Considering your example, initially you are having {"name":"f","serial":"f","price":"ff","gender":"M","color":"[{\"label\":\"Silver-Gold\",\"value\":\"Silver-Gold\"}]","size":"[{\"label\":\"S\",\"value\":\"S\"}]"}. The end result should be like {\"name\":\"f\",\"serial\":\"f\",\"price\":\"ff\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"color\":\"[{\"label\":\"Silver-Gold\",\"value\":\"Silver-Gold\"}]\",\"size\":\"[{\"label\":\"S\",\"value\":\"S\"}]\"}.

Comment: this is what I get for some reason: D/ccd: makePost: {"colors":"[{\"label\":\"Silver\",\"value\":\"Silver\"}, {\"label\":\"Silver-Gold\",\"value\":\"Silver-Gold\"}, {\"label\":\"Silver-Black\",\"value\":\"Silver-Black\"}]","gender":"M","imagesUri":"[]","name":"s","price":"s","serial":"s","sizes":"[{\"label\":\"S\",\"value\":\"S\"}]"}

Comment: Pretty Strange. There is no change in your generated Json String even after using those 2 replaceAll methods.  I would like to suggest 2 steps -  First, hardcode the JSON String message and check if you are able to successfully execute POST call. If this succeeds then indeed the problem should be resolved simply by correcting the JSON. So, the second step would be to make sure that JSON string is in correct format.

Comment: I hardcoded your json, still got 400, and Bad request, but I get this exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:4000/products/add
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)` and it logged from the server this: `{}`, as if the request is empty json

Comment: Your code has this line - 
        wr.writeBytes("PostData="+strings[1]);
So, is that how your Server expects the JSON data ? I mean does it need "PostData=" ? When your tried as successful POST request through POSTMAN, have you passed the payload that way ? If your payload should be JSON, then that text shouldn't be passed. You should have simply called -
        wr.writeBytes(strings[1]);

Comment: Also, if your payload is just a JSON, you must also add this line - httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: made the changes, still the same problem, would it help if I upload the schema of the json the server should get? im working on both backend and front end

Comment: yes, please post that. That might help more in finding the problem.

Comment: Since you are maintaining Server side code, I would suggest start simple. Expect only 1 field in your POST request JSON instead of whole bunch of fields. Check it from Postman that Server code is working. Observe all the request headers which are passed in Postman apart from the request body. Then, check if your client code works or not. The Content-Type header is a must for JSON type. Post your results back.

Answer (score 0):

If the server returns an error code, the getInputStream method would return an error. You should check which response code you get with `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` and continue based on the response. If it errors, you can use `getErrorStream()` to see the error.

Comment: this is what I get: `Response code: 400`, `Bad Request`, `buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource@d678e85).inputStream()
`

Comment: It seems the problem IS with what you send to the server, or the way you send it, as code 400 "indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)."